# Android screen orientation when device is blocked

Tags: android, screen-orientation

Is there any approach to get screen orientation, when device is blocked and screen is turned off? I tried

```
getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
```

and

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) mContext
    .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE))
    .getDefaultDisplay();
int rotation = display.getRotation();
```

but both of them return "portrait" and "0" respectively when sreen is off, no matter what the actual orientation is.

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand what you mean by "*blocked*", but if the screen is turned off, the **OS** seems to set the orientation to **Portrait**. You can test this by getting an app to a **landscape** mode, lay it flat down and turning off the screen. When you turn on the screen again, the app is now in **portrait** mode. If the device is not flat you can visibly see the orientation changes from **portrait** to **landscape**.

Comment: I mean "screen off". So, it is not possible to get the true orientation if the screen is turned off? I thought about sensors etc.

Comment: Do you mean by "true orientation" the orientation of the device, independent of applications?

Comment: Yes I do. It's important for my app.

Comment: You can certainly use sensor, but portrait and landscape are relative. I can show you how to get the device rotation from sensor.

Comment: It would be very helpfull! Please, explain.

Comment: Look at my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175599/how-to-measure-the-tilt-of-the-phone-in-xy-plane-using-accelerometer-in-android/15149421#15149421 It used to be that android would change orientation for example Portrait to Landscape if the rotation as calculate from the link above is about 60 degrees. In another word, change of orientation occurs if change in rotation is about 60. But not any more in new version. You have to play around to adapt to your situation.