# How to track reverse orientations(reverseLandscape and reversePortrait) through any listeners?

Tags: android, android-sensors, android-orientation, android-resolution

Gone through several posts and threads on configuration and orientation changes but still I am not cleared.

As `onConfigurationChanged` being called only when `orientation` changes from `landscape` to `portrait` or either `portrait` to `landscape`(as name suggests), but is there any way to listen `reverseLandscape` or `reversePortrait` orientation changes through any kinda listers at any api level.

Or is it possible to listen `rotation` changes same like `onConfigurationChanged` ??

Any kinda help will be highly appreciated !!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2799001/1008278

Comment: I need listeners to track whenever device rotates from landscape to reversLandscape or portrait to reversePortrait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use accelerometer and magnetic field sensors to calculate the device rotation and then call

```
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
```

when the rotation is at certain value. The way to calculate the rotation is at my answer [How to measure the tilt of the phone in XY plane using accelerometer in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175599/how-to-measure-the-tilt-of-the-phone-in-xy-plane-using-accelerometer-in-android/15149421#15149421)

Comment: thanks for your reply, but i don't wanna go for that much calculations to know just orientation as i thought their will be any call back listeners which will give the rotation or orientation whenever device rotates, bad luck i dint found answer yet !! +1

Comment: Actually, you do not need to use sensors to get the rotation. Just register for OrientationEventListener. It will give you the rotation angle.

Comment: what i want is already mentioned in my question, reverseLandscape and reversePortrait !!

Comment: Yes, I understand. OrientationEventListener gives you the angle as you rotate the device. It will not tell you if the device is in Portrait or Landscape or whatever else. All I meant is you can use the value return by the OrientationEventListener to call getRotation when that value passed certain value, say +- 160.

Comment: that sounds good let me try, if it works i will accept your answer.

Comment: I implement the idea with a simple change of a textview and it works out quite well. I posted the code answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585807/android-landscape-right-to-landscape-left-event/15595770#15595770

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve which of the 4 orientations is currently active by calling

```
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
```

Knowing when to call it can be tricky, as the system won't notify you if you go straight from `portrait` to `reversePortrait` for instance. The only way to achieve that is using the device's sensors. This [article from the Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2010/09/one-screen-turn-deserves-another.html) should help you.