# Parallax motion accelerometer sensor

Tags: android, sensors

I am trying to bring a motion parallax effect to the view using Sensor type accelerometer as it support most of the android devices.

I have the following code in my `onSensorChanged()` method:

```
 float[] g = new float[3];
        g = sensorEvent.values.clone();
        float norm_Of_g = (float) Math.sqrt(g[0] * g[0] + g[1] * g[1] + g[2] * g[2]);
        // Normalize the accelerometer vector
        g[0] = g[0] / norm_Of_g;
        g[1] = g[1] / norm_Of_g;
        g[2] = g[2] / norm_Of_g;
        if (startingAngle == 999) {
            startingAngle = (float) (Math.acos(g[0]) * 180 / Math.PI);
            currentAngle = (float) (Math.acos(g[0]) * 180 / Math.PI);
            lowerLimitAngle = currentAngle - kRotationAngleLimit;
            upperLimitAngle = currentAngle + kRotationAngleLimit;
            initialScrollX = scrollView.getScrollX();
            pixelsPerDegree = ((simpleDraweeView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth()/ (2 * kRotationAngleLimit)));

        }

        currentAngle = (float) (Math.acos(g[0]) * 180 / Math.PI);
        if (currentAngle >= lowerLimitAngle && currentAngle <= upperLimitAngle) {
            xOffset = (startingAngle - currentAngle) * pixelsPerDegree + initialScrollX;
        }
//
        scrollView.setScrollX((int) xOffset);
```

This works perfectly when i use [TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR).

On using [TYPE_ACCELEROMETER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), i get a fluctuate reading with it. Due to which the scroll is jerky.

Please help me on this.

[How to measure the tilt of the phone in XY plane using accelerometer in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175599/how-to-measure-the-tilt-of-the-phone-in-xy-plane-using-accelerometer-in-android)

Comment: Accelerometers are by their nature noisy input sources, subject to drift over time. There's no way to compensate for that in software, the only way is to combine input from other sensors (e.g. compass, gps, camera) in order to constantly re-calibrate the accelerometer.

Comment: @AaronD ok... you have any working approach that can work for non-gyroscope phones?