# Accelerometer Skips Readings

Tags: android

I am trying to measure angle at which my phone is using accelerometer. I refer to the method demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175599/how-to-measure-the-tilt-of-the-phone-in-xy-plane-using-accelerometer-in-android). But the problem is that when I rotate my phone at a high speed, it skips readings. For example, if I rotate my phone from `0` degrees to `90` degrees within a second, I get readings in logcat as : `0, 50, 90`. What I really want is to obtain all the values through which the phone has rotated, like `0,1,2,...,90`. Is it possible? If yes, what am I missing? Do I need to use gyroscope/magnetometer as well?

Answer (score 0):

Basically it was the sensor delay which was causing the issue. I resolved it by setting the delay to `SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST`.

Comment: Be aware that SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST is arbitrary depending on the device. For some devices it is 50Hz and on others it can be upwards of 300Hz....

Comment: @Kaleb Thanks for the heads up :) . However, I am using a delay value (45000) which is not defined in the SensorManager class. Do you think that might cause any issues?

Comment: That is about 22Hz and I have never come across a device that couldn't do at least 22Hz (you never know).  Also, defining a delay is Android 2.3+.

Comment: That means I'm on a safer side. I'm targeting API 15 as minimum. Thanks a lot though.