# How to detect device orientation changes with fixed portrait mode

Tags: android, orientation, sensors

I want to detect orientation changes when using a fixed orientation (natural) portrait mode. Following this question responses [How to measure the tilt of the phone in XY plane using accelerometer in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175599/how-to-measure-the-tilt-of-the-phone-in-xy-plane-using-accelerometer-in-android/15149421#15149421)
 I'm able to do it when the phone is not laying flat but it's not clear to me how to do it the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Yes You Detect Orientation Changes.

I hope My Gist will Be Helps You.

https://gist.github.com/fakefacebook/c07e15cb487d456d94ebaa15bbfeeedf

Comment: Thanks for your  response, so, you're ignoring the event when it fails?

`if (prevOrientation != currentOrientation && orientation != OrientationEventListener.ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN) {...`

Comment: no It ll Compares with Old Detected Orientation.because when Only Orientation Changes That time You Detect That. It ll not Repeat Same Orientation